# Changing Font Outline color inside a Table Cell with VBA using Application.CommandBar.ExecuteMSO

Tags: vba, office365, powerpoint

Win10x64 Office 365  PPT v 16.0.12325.202080 64-bits

I need to show a character with a yellow font color but a black outline, for readability purposes.  This character goes inside a Powerpoint table Cell.

The following link has a method that I'm currently using that consists of creating a dummy shape, adding text to it, modify the shape's textframe2 textrange font line properties and then copying it and pasting it back to the table cell.

http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-43787.html

This was asked 8 years ago, but I'm currently seeing the same behaviour where we can't directly manipulate the textframe2 wordart format of text inside a cell.  The program doesn't show an error but doesn't work.

I have given up on trying to modify the textrame2 textrange font line properties directly from VBA.

I have managed to get it to activate the font outline color using 
`Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("TextOutlineColorPicker")`

After it's activated I thought I could modify the textframe2 textrange font line properties, but it still doesn't work.

Is there an Application.CommandBars idMso for changing the font outline color and font outline line width inside a table cell?

Or another other than pasting the formatted text inside a table cell.

Edit:
Adding an image to illustrate what I mean by text color and text outline color and the menu used to show them in red circle:

[image]

Edit2
Added another snapshot to exemplify a character inside a cell with black outline and a character inside a cell without an outline
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example to access a `Table` on a given slide and change one cell's attributes. The example slide I'm using looks like this

[image]

The code itself creates a function that allows you to select a table from a particular slide, and a single cell within the table and highlight it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    HighlightTableCell 1, 2, 3
End Sub

Sub HighlightTableCell(ByVal slideNumber As Long, _
                       ByVal thisRow As Long, _
                       ByVal thisCol As Long)
    Dim theSlide As Slide
    Set theSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(slideNumber)

    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In theSlide.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoTable Then
            Dim theTable As Table
            Set theTable = shp.Table
            With theTable.Cell(thisRow, thisCol)
                With .Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Fill
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                    .Transparency = 0
                    .Solid
                End With
                With .Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Line
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
                    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
                    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
                    .Transparency = 0
                End With
            End With
        End If
    Next shp
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately this doesn't address my question.  I don't need to change the cell fill color.  I need to put the cell text in yellow and the cell font outline color in black.

Comment: I added the line to change the background color to red, you can delete that line if you wish. I added it because without it, my example table cell(2,3) shows yellow text on a white background. Very hard to see. Delete it if you wish. If the table has no style applied (no style, no grid), then only cell(2,3) shows a black border as pictured above.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me.  However my customer's request is not that the cell has black borders.  The request Is that the text inside the cell has an outline of black color .

Comment: I've updated the code with your improved explanation. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you PeterT, no need to apologize, I don't ask a lot of questions, so I apologize if my question wasn't clear from the beginning. I had already tried that code and tried yours too , it does set the text fill as yellow, but it doesn't set the outline color.  What is baffling is that it doesn't throw an error but it doesn't work.  If I try your code in a shape outside of a table it works, but not when the text is inside a Table Cell.

Comment: Sorry to ask this from you, would it be possible for you to run the code in the answer you kindly provided in your PP version, please? Just to discard if there's something wrong with my PC and/or PP version.

Comment: My code runs directly in Powerpoint 2013. Honestly at first it looked like it wasn't working until I increased the zoom level to over 200%. It was at that point that I could tell the text was yellow with a block outline. You may have to adjust the point size of your font, or the line weight of the outline.

Comment: I just tested the code at home using Powerpoint 2007 and the code sets the body of the font to yellow, but for some reason does not set the outline to black. Not sure what's going on there.

Comment: Thank you for checking this code back home.  Yes, sadly this seems to be a bug with the table object.  Do you have an idea if it's possible to trigger the text outline command in the commandbar?  I was thinking of using a sendkeys command but I think it'd be better to use the idMso of the command.

Answer (score 0):

This question should be answered by Microsoft Office developers.
Currently, to overcome this bug-some situation, I think, copying the formatted text outside the table and pasting it into a table cell is the only work-around for this trouble.

As you mentioned, according to John Wilson, one of the most brilliant PowerPoint MVPs(http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-43787.html), if we copy the text from a textbox or shape that is located outside of the table, the format of the text can be preserved even for the text in a table cell.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim shp As Shape, tshp As Shape
Dim sld As Slide
Dim tbl As Table
Dim r%, c%

If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionNone Then MsgBox "Select a table first.": Exit Sub
Set shp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
Set sld = shp.Parent

'add a temporary textbox for copying the formatted text into a cell
Set tshp = sld.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 541, 960, 540)
tshp.Visible = False

Set tbl = shp.Table
For r = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
    For c = 1 To tbl.Columns.Count
        '1) cell -> 'tshp'
        tbl.Cell(r, c).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Copy
        tshp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paste
        
        '2) outline the text in 'tshp'
        With tshp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .Weight = 0.2
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 127, 127)
        End With
        
        '3) 'tshp' -> cell
        tshp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Copy
        tbl.Cell(r, c).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paste
        
        '// the code below doesn't work
        'With tbl.Cell(r, c).shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Line
        'With tbl.Cell(r, c).shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Line
        '    .Visible = msoTrue
        '    .Weight = 0.5
        '    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 127, 127)
        'End With
    Next c
Next r

'remove the tempoarary textbox
tshp.Delete

End Sub
```

The above snippet creates a temporary textbox on left-top area of the slide and applies the outlined text format. Then, it copies the content of each cell to the temporary textbox and copy/paste the formatted text back to the cell. By using this method, we can apply the outlined text format to the text in a cell.